# D3.js ~ How to filter data values containing certain values/words?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

filtering data for a visualization I noticed that some values that do not correspond exactly to the values contained in the filter are not passed.
what I would like to do is to filter all the values in my dataset that contain that word, now i have:

```
stile.filter(function (d) { return d.StyleName == "Bold" || d.StyleName == "Demi" || d.StyleName == "Semibold"; });
```

I thought that adding the `.contains()` at the end of each value I want filtered could do the trick, like so:

```
stile.filter(function (d) { return d.StyleName.contains("Black") || d.StyleName.contains("Heavy") || d.StyleName.contains("Extrabold") || d.StyleName.contains("BoldNonextended"); })
```

But this didn't work unfortunately. Any help as always is really appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**: my dataset is a csv, the StyleName column has vairous values, like:
`Bold, Bold Extended, Regular` and so on. If I use the filter function that I have now, the data row containing `Bold Extendend` for example, is not returned because it has the word `Extended` also in it. That's what I'm trying to solve

Comment: Can you post some example data and expected output with your question?

Comment: added in the edit, it should be more clear now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `contains` try using `match()` and regular expressions:

```
stile.filter(function (d) { return d.StyleName.match(/Black/) || d.StyleName.match(/Heavy/) || d.StyleName.match(/Extrabold/) || d.StyleName.match(/BoldNonextended/); })
```

Comment: thanks it works! looks like I have to look into regular expressions again :)